# Correct Way To Program Threaded Conversations on Front End

Tags: java, ajax, database, hibernate, feed

I'm working on a project that requires threaded conversation: someone posts something new which creates a new thread and all replies are attached to that thread. I have this working great from a technical perspective, but I'm concerned about the security of my solution:

In order to reply to a thread, the thread's id, which is simply the database id of the thread, is in the html corresponding to the thread. This way, the javascript can get the thread id of the thread that's being replied to and use this to pass the response text and the thread id to the back end via ajax. It's also used to find where in the html the reply should be appended.

An example of this html would be:

```
<div id='thread_1' threadId='1'>Hey, how's it going?
  <div id='replies_1' threadId='1'>
  </div>
  <input id='reply_text_1' type='text' value='Reply...' threadId='1'></input>
  <input id='reply_button_1' type='submit' value='Reply' threadId='1'></input>
</div>
<div id='thread_2' threadId='2'>Anyone here?
  <div id='replies_2' threadId='2'>
    <div id='reply_2_1'>Yes, I'm here</div>
  </div>
  <input id='reply_text_2' type='text' value='Reply...' threadId='2'></input>
  <input id='reply_button_2' type='submit' value='Reply' threadId='2'></input>
</div>
```

It does not seem like having database id's in the front end code is a good idea - it seems like a potential security risk. Question is, how can I do this in a safe way? How can I associate the thread response from the front end to the thread in the database on the back end while not exposing my database id's?

FYI - in case it helps, the back end is Java + Spring + Hibernate.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having database IDs in the html is not a security risk.  In any site you'll often see them in the html and in the URLs.  The important thing is that you check in your callbacks that the current user has access to delete/read/reply to the message.

Comment: It _could_ be a maintanence issue, if you're passing around the table `JOIN` columns (and you delete rows, then re-org the ids); you may consider generating an 'external` id of some sort, that's not a join column (the hash of the origin row, possibly).  Other than that no, the id _can't_ be a security risk on it's own - you've got to have _some_ unique way to reference that thread, after all.  But do be careful about user permissions.

Comment: These comments are a great help... and I definitely feel a bit better about not having to redo everything! I think the suggestion about external id's is a good one and will definitely implement that. Good points about user perms, too... I've already built that out and should be good for the first iteration of the site. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Miles -- you could also hash the IDs if you are feeling really anal.  :)

Comment: Was thinking about using hashed ids. From looking at facebook's html, it looks like they're doing something like that. I don't want to use the extra cycles if it's not worth it though (running in the cloud ;)!

Comment: I'm revisiting this and have a question: I went with hashing the db id's (I guess I'm anal!) using md5, but these hashes are very long. Is there another method to produce shorter hashes? Or can I just take the first n characters of the md5 result and use that without drastically increasing the risk of collision?